# Where do I define symbols so that they're accessible in another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

In the excellent series of articles here: http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/comment-page-2/#comment-908 he explains a bit about how to use devise for auth and cancan for permissions. I have a question that seems much simpler (so it's omitted from those articles):

Where should I define the symbols such as :super_admin so that they're accessible by the Ability class? How should these definitions look?

I am pretty sure the definitions belong in the Role class, but if so, how are they available (in scope) in the Ability class as simply :super_admin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of symbols as efficient strings that are sort of like constants. You don't explicitly define them, you just use them - and that's probably where you're getting confused. Also, since you "just use" symbols they don't have a scope. If you mistype your symbol as `:duper_admin` then there's no error check for it since ruby will happily create that symbol for you.

In the article, the author is defining the roles in a `roles` table. So how do you compare the role in the database to your role symbol such as `:super_admin`? By using this method

```
def role?(role)
  return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end
```

It's used like so

```
if user.role? :super_admin
  can :manage, :all
...
```

The `role?` method is just converting the symbol to a string so it can be compared to the value in the database. There's no programmatic mapping going on between the `roles` table and the symbols being used. They're just manually being kept in sync.

Comment: At what point does the symbol :super_admin come to have the meaning? So, when you call the code as in the if block in your example, :super_admin would be passed into the role? method. this method would see whether or not the user has this role assigned, but what role would it be searching for? it says it will search for the ... i got it, that to_s changes :super_admin to "super_admin" and then camelize canges it to "SuperAdmin" so that means I need a role whose name is "SuperAdmin" in the db. Wow, must be tired, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The point of symbols is that the ruby interpreter only creates one copy of each symbol.  If you write `:foo` in one ruby file it will be the same as all other `:foo` in all other ruby files.  You do not have to define or declare a symbol ahead of time.

Comment: So when I am checking whether a user has a particular role associated, how will ruby compare the value from the database, to the symbol?